# How do I use RegionOfInterest in sensor_msgs?

Tags: sensor-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm using the kinect and Openni_launch to publish a pointcloud (pcl::point).
I want to extract the distance of a point given the pixel coordinates of that point.

so lets say, in the 640x480 pixel matrix, I want to extract the depth at cell 100x100.
I thought of using sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 and sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest. But I can't find out how to make them work together.

I currently have:

void roiing(sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest roi)
{
roi.x_offset = 100;
roi.y_offset = 100;
roi.height = 1;
roi.width = 1;
roi.do_rectify = false;
}

and then some Functions to subscribe to topics and do processing..

The region of interest doesn't change anything and I was wondering how I can make it work ? I can't find any code online where the RegionOfInterest message is used.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27996/how-do-i-use-regionofinterest-in-sensor_msgs-?/) by [samesimasemsom](https://answers.ros.org/users/1821/samesimasemsom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there somewhere specific that tells you to use a RegionOfInterest message? You can access a specific point from an organized pointcloud (which the openni driver produces) by using [cloud.at(u,v)](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.4.0/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a0dcdaca83e02807e154d82d42bdf631f).

Alternatively, if you just want the depth, you can subscribe to the depth image, and just index into the image, which will provide you with the depth.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2